# HttpPostedFileBase to API

Tags: c#, asp.net, httppostedfilebase

I am getting a error at this line `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);` I am passing in a `HttpPostedFileBase` which I am trying to send to a API.

> Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.Web.HttpInputStream'."}

```
  public string UploadToFileManager(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            var url = string.Format("Common/UploadToFileManager");

            var result = ApiHelpers.Post<HttpPostedFileBase> ("POST", url, file);

            //return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return "";
    }

    public static T Post<T>(string httpMethod, string url, object model)
    {
        try
        {
            var fullUrl = cmsApiUrl + url;

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

            Stream dataStream = null;
            WebRequest Webrequest;
            Webrequest = WebRequest.Create(fullUrl);


            Webrequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            Webrequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

            Webrequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
            Webrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + cmsApiKey);

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            Webrequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            dataStream = Webrequest.GetRequestStream();

            using (dataStream = Webrequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }

            WebResponse response = Webrequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            output.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
            response.Close();

            T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(output.ToString());
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>("");
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
            return result;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Is model variable null?

Comment: No model is not nullable

Comment: Did you check to make sure it is not null?

Comment: Yes the model is a httppostedFilewrapper has you can see in the image. The error {"Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.Web.HttpInputStream'."}

Comment: It doesn't seem such a good idea to serialize just any types, because not all types are suited to be serialized. Make your own DTOs which are only using intrinsic types or other DTOs and only get the data you want

Comment: Looks like Model is coming from a HttpInput Stream. Your code is doing a second HTTP Request using data that came from a different Input Stream.  Do you have more than one request/response?